# Custom Error Page in IIS 7.5 when a service (e.g. ColdFusion) is down

Tags: iis, coldfusion, custom-error-pages

For times when my ColdFusion service is down (which is rare), I need a "pretty" default HTML page that could display. The specific status error when ColdFUsion is down is a `503` error.

Based on [this question](/questions/18735881/creating-a-customised-503-page-in-iis-7) it appears that it could be difficult to override the default display of a 503 error message. I'm not an ASP/.NET developer, so I'm not sure whether the same circumstances would affect me, since I don't have an active application pool for my site in any case.

I tried adding a custom page and linking it to the 503 error using "Execute URL on this site". That removed the previous error page but did not render the HTML page (I verified that loading the page itself did work).  I tried the "Insert Content from Static File" option, and that led to an error (I tried tracking down the specifics, but wasn't able to find it either in the Event Viewer or the IIS logs).

So, I have two questions:

1. Absent a .Net application pool being in effect, is it possible to
   have a custom error page for handling 503 errors due to a service
   being down (I assume other application platforms besides ColdFusion
   might have similar behavior)
2. What is the preferred method for handling the error -- Executing a
   URL, including a static file, or performing a 302 redirect?

Comment: To clear up one of your questions, you do have an application pool in effect with your website. All websites running under IIS have an application pool assigned to them. This is how they are isolated from one another. In the case of a 503 error the "Execute URL on this site" doesn't make sense to me. Executing a URL would need a functioning service no? I would think you need to use the "Insert content from static file" option and just create an HTML file for it. Not sure why this gave you an error. Did you get the error when making the change itself or after you made a request and got a 503?

Comment: I got an error when requesting the page. After choosing the "Insert static file" option for a known HTML file and then re-requesting the main page for the site, I receive the following error: "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Comment: I just tested this successfully using IIS 8.0. I created a simple HTML page and placed it in the root of my website.  In IIS Manager I added a new custom error page for 503. I used the "Insert content from static file" option and selected the HTML file I created.  I stopped my ColdFusion instance and then browsed my site.  I see the message from my HTML file. How did you test creating the 503 error response?

Comment: I tried again. I got the following error when trying to use the Insert Static Content: "Absolute physical path is not allowed in system.webserver/httperrors section in web.config file. use relative path instead." I then enabled the absolute physical path option in the application config file. But then, when refreshing the site, I got the old "Macromedia" 503 error. It's as if it's ignoring my 503 error page!

Comment: Also, I experience extremely long latency for returning a known HTML file when the ColdFusion service is stopped -- like 15 seconds to download a < 1k HTML file.  Downloading images is instantaneous.

Answer (score 0):

This may be along time coming but what you need to do is add the error_page= /{any html page} to your isapi_redirect.properties file. See image or link.

[isapi_redirect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK1IK.jpg)